# Multicolumn-multivalue search in Excel?

Tags: excel, search

I have (large) Excel table with the following structure, where each cell may contain multiple values. The set of values is predetermined, but not known to the user, except for country (assuming good knowledge of geography).

```
Country                    Technology         Type of financing   Col 4
Peru, Vietnam, Thailand    solar, hydro       equity              xx
China, India               hydro, nuclear     debt, equity        xx
```

I would like to find the rows that match either “India” or “Vietnam” in the first column,
"hydro” in the second column, and “equity” or “debt” in the third column.

How would could one implement such a search in Excel?

The only solution that I know of is to use Custom AutoFilter with multiple “contains” statements with OR between the statements.

This is not very practical since one has to type the search expressions by hand and because the user does not know the range of possible values of the second and third col.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions: `Country` is in column `A`, `Technology` is in column `B` and so on. In your example, row `1` is the title row and row `2` is the first row of the data.

One way to do this would be to add a column with a formula like the following:

```
=AND(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("India",A2)),ISNUMBER(FIND("Vietnam",A2))),ISNUMBER(FIND("hydro",B2)),OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("equity",C2)),ISNUMBER(FIND("debt",C2))))
```

The result will be a `TRUE` value for all rows where your criteria are met.

Answer (score 0):

If you agree to use VBA, following the scheme:

[image]

add this code to the Change event...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("A3").Value = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$C$10").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:="*" & Range("A2").Value & "*"
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$C$10").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:="*" & Range("A2").Value & "*", Operator:=xlOr, _
        Criteria2:="*" & Range("A3").Value & "*"
    End If

    If Range("B3").Value = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$C$10").AutoFilter Field:=2, _
        Criteria1:="*" & Range("B2").Value & "*"
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$C$10").AutoFilter Field:=2, _
        Criteria1:="*" & Range("B2").Value & "*", Operator:=xlOr, _
        Criteria2:="*" & Range("B3").Value & "*"
    End If

    If Range("C3").Value = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$C$10").AutoFilter Field:=3, _
        Criteria1:="*" & Range("C2").Value & "*"
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$C$10").AutoFilter Field:=3, _
        Criteria1:="*" & Range("C2").Value & "*", Operator:=xlOr, _
        Criteria2:="*" & Range("C3").Value & "*"
    End If
End Sub
```

Set the Autofilter on. When you write in the upper cells, the autofilter it's updated automatically.

Comment: Many thanks! This is exactly what I needed. One detail, to your knowledge, is it possible to have three search fields? I tried it and could not make it to work. Could it be that that two search criteria is the maximum that autofilter can handle?

Answer (score 0):

For the Autofilter, yes. You can only have two criteria.
If you want to use more criteria you can use the advance Filter. Following this scheme:

[image]

In the Upper part you write the criteria you want. See the link:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-HP005200178.aspx#BMexample1
But quickly: row are AND , column are OR.
In the second part you build the format Advanced Filter want. On the third part you have the data filtered.
Add this code to the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ValR As Integer

    ValR = 0
    For i = 8 To 11
        If Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then ValR = i
        If Range("B" & i).Value <> "" Then ValR = i
        If Range("C" & i).Value <> "" Then ValR = i
    Next
    Range("A13:C17").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Range("A7:C" & ValR), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Add the formula in A8:

```
=IF(A2<>"";CONCATENATE("=*";A2;"*");"")
```

and autocomplete A8:C11.
It's a little bit complicated to assembly the criteria, but are more powerfull.